# Php script for fcm

Tags: php, android, linux

I am developing an android app implementing FCM. For testing purpose I need to implement my own script to send data.I am using linux and I am quite naive about server side implementation. I have a php script which is supposed to send data.It is on localhost.So what do I need to do to run the script. Do I need to bind my localhost to my IP .?? Also how do I know if my script has successfully send data.Right now I am not getting any error. I am using command line php -f var/www/html/filename. Thanks

Comment: you can run via localhost also, dont need to run using ip. if you are using own xampp server to run android app, then you need to set server ip to mobile device.

Comment: to learn more **fcm-php** see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50484784/5912012