# How to send FCM notification using PHP?

Tags: php, android, curl, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to send FCM using PHP code/web browser.

But the problem is when I send it using PHP web browser:

- FCM notification only appear on virtual devices.
- FCM notification does not appear on real phone devices.

And I can only send FCM notifications to real phone devices using Firebase Console.

Can somebody help? The code is below.

```
<?php
require "init.php";
global $con;
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        $message     = $_POST['message'];
        $title       = $_POST['title'];
        $path_to_fcm = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'; 
        $server_key  = "AAAA2gV_U_I:APA91bHA28EUGmA3BrDXFInGy-snx8wW6eZ_RUE7EtOyM99pbfrVZU_ME-FU0O9_dUxYpM30OYF8KWYlixod_PfwbgLNoovzdkdJ4F-30vY8X_tBz0CMrajCIAgbNVRfw203YdRGli";    
        $sql     = "SELECT fcm_token FROM fcm_table";
        $result  = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $row     = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            $key = $row[0];
        $headers = array('Authorization:key=' .$server_key, 'Content-Type:application/json');
        $fields  = array('to' => $key, 'notification' => array('title' => $title, 'body'=> $message));
        $payload = json_encode($fields);
        $curl_session = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_fcm);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
        $result = curl_exec($curl_session);
        curl_close($curl_session);
        mysqli_close($con);
    }   
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FCM Notification</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='fcm_notification.php' method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Title : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="title" required="required" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Message : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="message"  required="required" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send notification"></td>

            </tr>
        </table> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: By device, you mean Android, right?

Comment: yup. android devices

Comment: Are you able to properly get the registration tokens for the emulators? Have you tried sending a message using a simple cURL response and see if iut still doesn't receive any messages?

Comment: yes . registration token work from emulator to database .

Comment: Can you check this [link.](https://devnote.in/how-to-send-push-notifications-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-with-php/)

Answer (score 5):

By the following way you can send push notification to mobile using google FCM. For me its works as expected. Add the key `'priority' => 'high'`

```
function sendPushNotification($fields = array())
{
    $API_ACCESS_KEY = 'YOUR KEY';
    $headers = array
    (
        'Authorization: key=' . $API_ACCESS_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    return $result;
}

$title = 'Whatever';
$message = 'Lorem ipsum';
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => ['deviceID'],
    'data'          => '',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'notification' => array(
        'body' => $message,
        'title' => $title,
        'sound' => 'default',
        'icon' => 'icon'
    )
);

sendPushNotification($fields);
```

Comment: deviceID ? is it the same with sender ID from FCM ?

Comment: From mobile when you trying to connect google FCM its send you a registration_id/deviceID whatever you call it. It look like below

`fxRKtQfyP5Y:APA91bGkjkerOGAVCdZFy6f9G-gmXHJwRNAeKELIWMgddDKQW34MZw0LQPPluM1hKCzYsfcVVnuwbSJEjctAKs2JAaCLUEeSM6QEW7qVZ281O9TUOa8mJ4Hb8qNo_qHoc9eSNvsGjrKY`

Answer (score 0):

you can create function which send push notification for devices .

```
// firebase access key
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AAAAAG78XmM:APA91bFRHpzuEIgiQRmPUm4uRy8bygNGr1h2Oq3ydc5WtKbrfJA8NVAaGIAxbQELfcOWwN2OR4pf5NzSRuuWOYj_P-XXXXXXXX');        
// target device 'fcm' id
$device[0]='JI8YHo7GEo:APA9-aGWOU3U3CXXXXXXXXXXX';
$device[1]='JI8YHo7GEo:APA9-aGWOU3U3CXXXXXXXXXXX';

    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    // "to": "e1w6hEbZn-8:APA91bEUIb2JewYCIiApsMu5JfI5Ak...",   // for single device (insted of "registration_ids"=>"$device"  )
    $data = array("registration_ids" => $device,            // for multiple devices 
        "notification" => array( 
        "title" => "Party Night", 
        "body" => "Invitation for pool party!",
        "message"=>"Come at evening...",
        'icon'=>'https://www.example.com/images/icon.png'
    ),
        "data"=>array(
        "name"=>"xyz",
        'image'=>'https://www.example.com/images/minion.jpg'
        ) 
    ); 

    $data_string = json_encode($data); 
    $headers = array ( 'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY, 'Content-Type: application/json' ); 
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url ); 
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true ); 
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers ); 
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); 
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

for more details refer this

**to** – Type String – (Optional) [Recipient of a message]
The value must be a single registration token, notification key, or topic. Do not set this field when sending to multiple topics

**registration_ids** – Type String array – (Optional) [Recipients of a message]
Multiple registration tokens, min 1 max 1000.

**priority**– Type String – (Optional) [ default normal]
Allowed values normal and high.

**delay_while_idle** – Type boolean – (Optional) [default value false]
true indicates that the message should not be sent until the device becomes active.

**time_to_live** – Type JSON number – (Optional) [default value 4 week maximum 4 week]
This parameter specifies how long (in seconds) the message should be kept in FCM storage if the device is offline

**data** – Type JSON Object
Specifies the custom key-value pairs of the message’s payload. 
eg. {“post_id”:”1234″,”post_title”:”A Blog Post Title”}

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can receive it in onMessageReceived() as Map data…

**When in the background** – Apps receive the notification payload in the notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user taps on the notification.

**When in the foreground** – App receives a message object with both payloads available.

```
public class FcmMessageService extends FirebaseMessagingService{
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //onMessageReceived will be called when ever you receive new message from server.. (app in background and foreground )
    Log.d("FCM", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
    Log.d("FCM", "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    if(remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("post_id") && remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("post_title")){
        Log.d("Post ID",remoteMessage.getData().get("id").toString());
        Log.d("Post Title",remoteMessage.getData().get("post_title").toString());
        // eg. Server Send Structure data:{"post_id":"12345","post_title":"A Blog Post"}
    }
}}
```